# Не выводятся переменные в PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
 $adress="30-річчя Перемоги, б-р.1";
 $db = mysql_connect("localhost","kernozz_db","") OR DIE 
("Not");


$tablehead = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `tariffofsite` WHERE `A` = 
'Дом'");
$res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM  `tariffofsite` WHERE  `A` = '". 
$adress ."' LIMIT 0 , 30");

$cont = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
$head = mysqli_fetch_row($tablehead);


    for ($i=0; $i < 17; $i++) { //циклом выводим заголовоки столбцов        
        echo "asdsad". $head[$i]."  ". $cont[$i];
    }
```

Данный код отрабатывает на локалке, но на сервере он просто не выводит переменную c с которой провели операцию `mysqli_fetch_row`
Символы которые выводятся между или до переменной выводятся нормально.

Т.е. должно быть[image: Ljk;yj]

А на хостинге

[image: На деле]

Comment: кодировка на хостинге

Comment: Кодировка базы? Как это вообще решать?

Comment: **$ter= htmlspecialchars($row['ter_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');** может это пых не принимает кодировку украинских символов .
$row['ter_name'] сдесь своё поле подставь.
ALTER TABLE **твоя таблица** CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;